# Can I install Visual Studio 2005 without disrupting Visual Studio 2008 and 2010?

Tags: visual-studio

I have VS2008 and VS2010 on brand new Win7. Can I install VS2005 afterwards ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say NO, if you want to avoid unexpected problems. It is generally recommended to install Visual studio versions in order they are released, by Microsoft.

See
Installing Visual Studio Versions Side-by-Side
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx

Comment: Unfortunate they don't tell how to do in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

If you were asking could you install 2008 after you've installed 2010 I'd say go ahead and try. I would be surprised if there were any issues. However 2005 was notoriously buggy even when installed correctly so I wouldn't recommend it. Visual Studio is such a complex beast installing an older version after the fact may seem like it's working and then cause weird issues later and you won't even realize why.

I'd recommend uninstalling 2010, 2008 and then starting over.

Comment: I remember I have uninstalled VS2010 once and trying to reinstall failed I had to reinstall my whole OS so I would avoid also :)